# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at index.js:1 error in lodash

Tags: node.js, node-modules

getting console error
module.exports = require('./lodash');

My Package.json file is below

{

```
"scripts": {

},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
  "lodash": "^4.11.1"
 
  
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/lodash": "^4.11.1",
  "typescript": "~3.5.3"
}
```

}

Comment: The question is unclear! Can you add more details? It looks like most of the code. @sha

Comment: when i run  my project there is s console error module is not found  error is in module.exports = require('./lodash');

Answer (score 1):

You are importing [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library wrong way, all you need

```
// Load the full build.
var _ = require('lodash');
// Load the core build.
var _ = require('lodash/core');
// Load the FP build for immutable auto-curried iteratee-first data-last methods.
var fp = require('lodash/fp');

// Load method categories.
var array = require('lodash/array');
var object = require('lodash/fp/object');

// Cherry-pick methods for smaller browserify/rollup/webpack bundles.
var at = require('lodash/at');
var curryN = require('lodash/fp/curryN');
```

OR

in angular component you can simply import any of the lodash method which you are using

```
import { map, tail, times, uniq, get } from 'lodash';
```

Comment: I am importing in angular component like -> import * as _ from 'lodash';

Comment: @sha not a good approach instead of importing all (*) you should be specific like I did in my answer `import { get, ... } from 'lodash';` whatever method you required import only that specific

Comment: import { map, tail, times, uniq, get } from 'lodash'; using like this     ERROR in src/app/pipes/add/add.component.ts(1061,82): error TS2686: '_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

Comment: @sha this is bcz of your tsConfigration try debug that or you can keep using `import * as _ from 'lodash'`.

Comment: I Tried in the above way but stiil facing the same bug import { reject } from 'lodash';

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
const _ = require("lodash")
const ver = _.VERSION
console.log(ver);
```

As per the docs...

Comment: Its working in console i am getting the error module.exports = require('./lodash')

Comment: Try deleting your cache folder and rebuilding the project... also will be helpful to supple any logs from your terminal or a stack trace

Comment: Also check you package.json file ... there is a mismatch between you dev dependencies and your regular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include a path for lodash. You need

```
const _ = require('lodash')
```